# Update Windows using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

I'm currently having my internship at a elementary school. I got the task to setup users for some classes, with that I also need run Windows Update too. 
So I have been scanning Google for something that does this in vb.net since I have been coding some in that before. I din't find much on the subject except for "C:\Windows\System32\wuauclt.exe /detectnow" though when I run it it don't seem to do much.

So the question is it there is any command or file you can run to make Windows download and install updates?
To clarify it need to work on Windows 7, I'm also writing the program in .NET 3.5.

Please let me know if you need any more information!

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with programming. Better ask it in a more adequate forum.

Comment: @varocarbas How doesn't it? I want to do this in VB.net? or batch, aren't they programming langues?

Comment: An example of programming-related question is "how can I execute an external program by relying on the programming language X?". You are asking how to interact with Windows; typing the command manually or writing it inside an application does not really matter. All what you want to know is the exact command line, that is, a non-programming-related question.

Comment: @varocarbas Okay, fine. I'll post it on another forum...

Comment: whats wrong with Windows Update?  Why code something and reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Keltari What do you suggest I do then?